# SEGFAULT using libvlc

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, libvlc

When I try to play a music with libvlc it throws a segfault...

#### Code :

```
 libvlc_instance_t * inst;
 libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
 libvlc_media_t *m;
 inst = libvlc_new (0, NULL);
 m = libvlc_media_new_path(inst, "test.mp3"); //SEGFAULT here !
 mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (m);
 libvlc_media_release (m);
 libvlc_media_player_play (mp);
 Sleep(10);
 libvlc_media_player_stop (mp);
 libvlc_media_player_release (mp);
 libvlc_release (inst);
```

I built libvlc.lib by following to instruction from [GenerateLibFromDll](https://wiki.videolan.org/GenerateLibFromDll/).

Comment: First, you should check the return of `media_new_path` for NULL. So according to the  [docs](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__core.html#ga915aa5778053d7b52ff9f6ba6e2f7764), an error occured. Look at the [docs for error messages](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__error.html)

Comment: Check the result of `libvlc_new (0, NULL)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Christopher and Kay comments I found that the `inst` pointer was set to `nullptr`. I also copied the plugins folder to the Debug directory now thats fine.